# What Java type to use to represent a currency value in a web service?

Tags: java, web-services, types, jaxb, marshalling

I'm creating a web service in Java that will be consumed by an external application, probably written in C#.  In my Purchase bean, I have a Currency object for the total cost.  However, this leads to the following error:

```
Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.util.Currency does not have a no-arg default constructor.
```

I found [a solution](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2005/09/using_jaxb_20s.html) to create a custom XML Adapter to handle the Currency marshalling/unmarshalling:

```
public class CurrencyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String,Currency> {
  public Currency unmarshal(String val) throws Exception {
    return Currency.getInstance(val);
  }
  public String marshal(Currency val) throws Exception {
    return val.toString();
  }
}
```

Could I use that custom XML Adapter, or use a BigDecimal (or other type) object to represent the cost?

Comment: `XmlAdapter` is the correct approach, that's what it's there for.

Comment: Should I marshal it as a string as in the example above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are conflating a currency (which is a named unit) and a cost (which is some quantity in that unit). You can't represent a Currency as a BigInteger, because a Currency is not a quantity.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant until I was getting an illegal argument exception when trying to set the currency to a numeric value.  Only then did I look at the javadoc and realize what you meant.  Anyway, the question remains - what data type should I use to pass an actual cost quantity in a web service?

Comment: You should use any data type that represents, as an integer, the number of the smallest unit of currency. For example, in dollars, your quantity would be the number of *cents*, although some transactions requre tenths of cents, in which case your number (still an integer) would represent the number of tenths of a cent. As long as you don't use floating point, you'll be ok. Then you just have to pick a data type large enough to handle the maximum transaction size without overflow.